# If an infinite sequence is convergent to limit L, are its subsequences also convergent to the same limit L?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Lets say our infinite sequence is A(n) and we have two subsequences of A(n):

1. A(2n)
2. A(2n-1)

If the infinite sequence A(n) is convergent to L (for all values where n is greater or equal to 1), does this THEN mean that the two subsequences are also convergent to L?

Would it be the same vice-versa? (If the two subsequences are convergent to L, does this THEN mean that A(n) is also convergent to the same L?)

Comment: **(for all values where n is greater or equal to 1)** This statement is unnecessary if you know the definition of convergence.

Comment: $\{A_n\}$ converges to $L$ if and only if all of the subsequences converge to the same $L$. So your last question is false.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, all the subsequences of the infinite sequence must converge to the same limit L as the original sequence.

This is also true for the vice- versa case. If the $2$ subsequences (provided they cover the entire sequence) converge to a limit $L$, the original sequence converges to the same limit.

However, a stricter condition is that only when all the subsequences of the original sequence converges to the limit $L$, the infinite sequence will itself converge to the same limit $L$.

Comment: Surely the *vice versa* case is only true if the subsequences "cover" the entire sequence.  These do, but that should be made clear, probably.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Could you perhaps provide a formal proof in showing this?

Comment: $\{c_n\} \subset  \{b_n\} \subset \{a_n\} $. Surely if $b,c$ converge to same limit doesn't imply $a$ converges to the same limit.